# Test connection created by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, database, session, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to test a connection created in `SQLAlchemy`? I am starting my studies in `SQLAlchemy` and in my project, i allow the user to build the `engine` corresponding to his database. Assuming that i want to check if a user used the correct parameters in the creation of the `engine`, would i be able to test it and notify him if any parameter is wrong?

EX:

```
some_engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
```

This is a correct way to build the engine. Now, suppose that the user name was misspelled, or even the port or host was misspelled, would it be possible to test this connection and point out the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
conn = some_engine.connect()
conn.close()
```

connect will raise en error if unsuccessful.

Comment: This works perfectly for almost all cases of incorrectly typed information, however, it does not point out an error if the user types the database schema incorrectly

Comment: Then you will probably have to run some simple query in the database.